# When implementing Trie Data Structure using smart pointer is it necessary to use shared pointers?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, trie

Link to gfg: [Trie Data Structure using smart pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-data-structure-using-smart-pointer-and-oop-in-c/?ref=rp)

I came across this implementation of Trie Data Structure using shared pointers. But I don't understand the purpose of using shared pointers.

Can we not simply use unique pointers here?

Comment: Did you read the page you linked? There is a paragraph that starts with, *"Why shared_ptr instead of all other smart pointers (auto_ptr, unique_ptr, weak_ptr)?*

Comment: Sorry, I understand now.

Comment: Having read that article, that's a bad implementation, and you shouldn't copy it. Do it yourself with `unique_ptr`

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thanks @Caleth